# Replacing all the non-integers with a new integer in a column python

Tags: python, pandas, replace

So i have a column called owners that looks like this

```
'Owned by Terrick Inc.',
 nan,
 'Owned by MHPI Inc.',
 'Owned by Zeman Homes & Neighborhoods',
 'Owned by Santefort Neighborhood Properties',
 'Owned by MHPI Inc.',
 'Owned by MHPI Inc.',
 nan,
 2,
 nan,
 5,
 'Owned by RHP Properties',
 'Owned by Zeman Homes & Neighborhoods',
 'Owned by Zeman Homes & Neighborhoods',
 'Owned by Gateway Manufactured Home Community',
 3,
 nan,
 'Owned by Zeman Homes & Neighborhoods',
 'Owned by MHPI Inc.',
 nan,
 'Owned by Indian Trails LLC',
 'Owned by Zeman Homes & Neighborhoods',
 1,
 'Owned by Lake View Manufactured Home Community',
 5,
 2,
 'Owned by Zeman Homes & Neighborhoods'
```

I am trying to change all the values that are not number to a number 10. but for some reason it is not working. I tried 2 methods this is the first, but this just replaces the whole column with 9 so its not taking in my conditions.

```
df['Owner'][(df['Owner'] != 0) | (df['Owner'] != '1') | (df['Owner'] != '2') | (df['Owner'] != 3) | (df['Owner'] != 4) | (df['Owner'] != 5) | (df['Owner'] != 6)] = 9
```

the second method i used was a loop with an if statment. but this isnt doing anything to the list

```
for i in df['Owner']:
    if i == 1:
        pass
    elif i == 2:
        pass
    elif i == 3:
        pass
    elif i == 4:
        pass
    elif i == 5:
        pass
    elif i == 6:
        pass
    elif i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        i = 9
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Owner'] = [10 if type(x) is not int else x for x in df['Owner']]
```

Should do it. It reads like plain English like so often in Python.

Comment: hi Gwang, so i used a replace to get the 1,2,3,4,5,6. so the dtype is still all the same i believe. When i tried your code it changed everything to 10 as well. I guess a better way of ecplaining what i want to do is to just group all the remain stuff not in numbers together for bivariate analysis

Comment: @doskitele it just means that the type of the numbers in the column are not `np.dtype(int)`. But perhaps they are simply `int`? Did you tried the second suggested version using `in`?

Comment: @doskitele Now I changed to just `int` because it was just `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the `type` function, and compare to `int`, then use `where` to keep the integers and replace the rest with 10:

```
df['Owner'] = df['Owner'].where(df['Owner'].map(type).eq(int), 10)
```

output:

```
  Owner
0    10
1    10
2     2
3    10
4     5
5    10
```

Used input:

```
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'Owner': ['Owned by MHPI Inc.', nan, 2, nan, 5, 'Owned by RHP Properties',]})
```

Comment: It should be `.neq(int)` or?

Comment: This worked thank you so much

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim no why? Actually you could use `ne` with `mask`

Comment: @mozway - I thought negation was somewhoe missing. But it's true your code works perfectly. Ah I was confused by `np.where()`.

Comment: @mozway because in `np.where(<condition>, x)` `x` would mean replace where condition is true by x. But perhaps not even that is true ...